# SQLServer: How to drop corrupted Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I have a corrupted Foreign Key Constraint in one of our databases.

I can't drop it - because it does not exist. It does not exist in sys.sysobjects and sys.objects. SQLServer Management Console does not list it as well,

Yet, I can't recreate the Foreign Key Constraint because it already exists in the schema (error: an object with the same identifier does already exist).

How can I fix that? Which metadata tables are responsible for that?

Comment: Just check sysindexes too. I am not sure, but worth a try.

Comment: If there's definitely no other object in the database with that name (I hope you've been searching sys.objects based on just name at this point), open a ticket with MS.

Comment: Yes, there's definitely not one single object with the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is if it's somehow doing a case-sensitive match and you're passing in a name with different case than what the server has stored.  Try this:

```
select fk.[name]
from sys.foreign_keys fk
inner join sys.objects o
   on fk.[referenced_object_id] = o.[object_id]
where lower(o.[name]) = lower('your table here')
```